# Como colocar um atalho global para reiniciar servidores em modo de debug no Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Como eu posso configurar o Eclipse (estou usando o Kepler no momento) para que ao apertar um atalho no teclado, por exemplo, F12, o servidor do Tomcat inicie ou reinicie em modo Debug?

Eu consegui fazer o atalho F12 funcionar, mas eu tive que necessáriamente configurar para *In Servers View*. E isso me faz ir até a aba de servidores para eu poder aplicar o atalho.

Se eu colocar uma outra opção, por exemplo, *In Windows* ou *Editing Java Source* ele não roda, fala: *The selection did not contain any resource that can run on a server*.

Como eu posso contornar esse problema? Ou seja, como eu posso iniciar e reiniciar o servidor a partir de um atalho global do teclado de qualquer lugar do eclipse?

Acrescento que no momento preciso usar dois servidores, ou seja, minha lista de Servers têm dois Tomcats e eu preferia uma solução que desse para disparar um determinado servidor sempre. Mas, se for possível fazer o atalho funcionar, posso tentar deixar apenas um servidor na lista. De qualquer forma, ser der para personalizar para o atalho atuar sempre em algum deles seria ainda melhor.

Answer (score 1):

No meu eu inicio o servidor como debug segurando Alt+Shift+D, então solto e em seguida pressiono R.